# C++ how to implement settings of different types that are serializable/deserializable

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to implement a system where I have a template class which implements a Serializable interface.

Right now, the interface contains serialize/deserialize methods while the template Setting class has get/set, and private members settingName, settingValue and a template function T adaptType() to adapt string to correct type using the >> operator (https://gist.github.com/mark-d-holmberg/862733). The file also contains a custom struct with << and >> operators overloaded for everything to work.

Settings are serialized in form of settingName:settingValue or settingName:val1;val2;val3 in case of the struct.

There are two problems I'm facing with this design:

1. I want to hold all these setting objects in a map<string, ISerializable*(?)> to access them but then I can't call other functions get/set on these objects because the interface doesn't define the methods (they must be in Setting class because their type depends on the template type), if I switch the second type in map to template class, I must define a concrete type
2. When deserializing there's no way to know which type it is and ISerializable can't be instantiated since it's an abstract class, again I need to know which type I'm deserializing and instantiate the Setting class with appropriate type

Is there a better way to design this or something I'm missing, note that I am not very proficient with c++

Bit of a background for the problem:
I'm working on an embedded device where settings need to be loaded/saved to flash memory but there's also another framework running on the device which holds these settings in RAM and serves them on a webserver to be edited, I cannot change this part. My goal is to manually save these settings to my custom class that manages settings and save/load to flash so it is persistent between reboots and synced with the web framework.

Any help or advice is welcome

Comment: It would be useful if you could share a toy example the interface and where you're coming unstuck... but based on your description I suspect for question 1 you might find a "double dispatch" approach will work. For question 2 you might try using the factory pattern, so when you serialise you store some representation of the type, and then when deserialising you pass that string/enum/etc value to the factory and it creates the concrete type for you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem it is similar to what the Oops library is doing. It creates a Type Descriptor class for all types having similar functionality: giving some description of the type and provide text and binary serialization for them. It is also designed to handle configuration, so it even may help to solve your problem.
It worth to have a look at least for getting some ideas: https://bitbucket.org/barczpe/oops